# Create Kendo UI grid using AngularJs and WebApi

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

What is the best way to create Kendo UI grid using angular and web api (for backend)? I am use MVC structure.
My model looks like:

```
public class Category
{

    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

In web api controller i have following methods:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories() {}
public HttpResponseMessage PostCategory(Category category) {}
public HttpResponseMessage PutCategory( Category category) {}
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteCategory(Category category) {}
```

Now, I wish to implement kendo ui grid using angular. How can I do that? 
I am read kendo ui demos: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular and documentation but I don't understand how can implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a mostly working example attached to one of my questions here

[AngularJS kendo grid binding to angular service webapi - sorts always null when parsing with [fromuri]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946096/angularjs-kendo-grid-biding-to-angular-service-webapi-sorts-always-null-when-p)

if you attach the service url directly to the dataSource.transport instead of using a service like I did you should be good to go....

Just take out my read:xxxxx section and replace with

```
read: {
  url: "YourWEBAPIURL",
  dataType: "json" 
}
```